# How to obtain partial derivative symbol in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I would like Mathematica to return symbolic partial derivative instead of actual derivative.

```
StressMatrix = ( {
    {\[Sigma]11, \[Sigma]12, \[Sigma]13},
    {\[Sigma]21, \[Sigma]22, \[Sigma]23},
    {\[Sigma]31, \[Sigma]32, \[Sigma]33}
   } );
varList = ( {
   {\[Rho], \[Theta], z}
  } )
StressMatrix[[2, 3]]
varList[[1, 1]]
D[StressMatrix[[2, 3]], varList[[1, 1]]]
```

The code above returns zero but I would like it to return symbolically Partial derivative of Sigma[[2,3]] with respect to rho.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Inactivate`,

```
Inactivate[D[StressMatrix[[2, 3]], varList[[1, 1]]]]
```

or `Hold`

```
Hold[D[StressMatrix[[2, 3]], varList[[1, 1]]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I am looking for Mathematica to return just partial derivative symbol of sigma23 with respect to rho.  The result I am looking for would be typed in latex as shown: \frac{\partial{\sigma_{12}}}{\partial\rho}

Comment: Inactivate is returning:Inactive[D][
 Inactive[Part][{{\[Sigma]11, \[Sigma]12, \[Sigma]13}, {\[Sigma]21, \
\[Sigma]22, \[Sigma]23}, {\[Sigma]31, \[Sigma]32, \[Sigma]33}}, 2, 
  3], \[Rho]]

Comment: Hold is returning: Hold[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(varList[[1, 1]]\)]\(StressMatrix[[
   2, 3]]\)\)]

Answer (score 0):

Various methods, including specified values (which need to be set *after* hold).

```
Clear[σ23]

StressMatrix = Map[Hold,
   {{σ11, σ12, σ13}, {σ21, σ22, σ23}, {σ31, σ32, σ33}}, {2}];
varList = {{ρ, θ, z}};

σ23 = 4 ρ^2;

expr = StandardForm[
   "∂" <> StringTake[ToString[StressMatrix[[2, 3]]], {6, -2}]/
    "∂" <> ToString[varList[[1, 1]]]];

symbolic = Inactive[D][ReleaseHold@StressMatrix[[2, 3]], varList[[1, 1]]];

result = D[ReleaseHold@StressMatrix[[2, 3]], varList[[1, 1]]];

Row[{expr, " = ", symbolic, " = ", result}]
```

[image]

Alternatively

```
symbolic2 = StringJoin["D[",
  StringTake[ToString[StressMatrix[[2, 3]]], {6, -2}], ",", 
  ToString@varList[[1, 1]], "]"];

Row[{expr, " = ", symbolic2, " = ", ToExpression[symbolic2]}]
```

[image]

And finally

```
Clear[σ23]

StressMatrix = 
  Map[HoldForm, {{σ11, σ12, σ13}, {σ21, σ22, σ23}, {σ31, σ32, σ33}}, {2}];
varList = {{ρ, θ, z}};

σ23 = 4 ρ^2;

expr = StandardForm[
   "∂" <> ToString[StressMatrix[[2, 3]]]/
    "∂" <> ToString[varList[[1, 1]]]];

symbolic = Inactive[D][ToString@StressMatrix[[2, 3]], varList[[1, 1]]];

result = D[ReleaseHold@StressMatrix[[2, 3]], varList[[1, 1]]];

Row[{expr, " = ", symbolic, " = ", result}]
```

[image]